# Search & Replace in tree

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I want to do a search and replace in a tree, searching for a subtree and replacing it with another:

```
type Tree =
    | A of string
    | B of int
    | C of List<Tree>

let rec replace search repl subject =
    if subject = search then
        repl
    else
        match subject with
            | C l -> C (l |> List.map (replace search repl))
            | _ -> subject
```

Is there an easier way or more generic way to do this and similar transformations (e.g. contains)? It seems a very close fit for fmap (Haskell) but I can't make it work.

Comment: you should have a look at [zippers](http://tomasp.net/blog/tree-zipper-query.aspx/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function looks quite readable to me. It can be shortened like this:

```
let rec replace search repl = function
    | x when x = search -> repl
    | C l -> List.map (replace search repl) l |> C
    | x -> x
```

with `contains` looking very similar.

To improve generality, you could try checking whether the tree data structure and the discriminated union for the tree's content can be separate types, allowing to type the data as `MyTree<MyContent>`. This may or may not apply to the problem, but where it does, splitting container and content greatly increases both re-usability and readability.

For a generic `MyTree<'T> = Leaf of 'T | Branch of MyTree<'T> list`, checking for a node (branch or leaf) isn't too long:

```
let rec containsNode node = function
    | Leaf _ as x -> x = node
    | Branch l as b -> b = node || List.exists (containsNode node) l
```

nor is the function to replace any node:

```
let rec replaceNode node newNode = function
    | x when x = node -> newNode
    | Branch l -> List.map (replaceNode node newNode) l |> Branch
    | Leaf _ as x -> x
```

In other words, minimalistic types and pattern matching can be nice for this type of problem. *Though they aren't always. Please don't mind this post if it doesn't apply.*